# How do I pull a image by gridview position to another activity

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

i want to put the image that the user choose from the gridview to another department , now :  bitmaps.get(position); - give me the image bring me the selected image by Location, but the app crashes..

first code of one activity:

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SpcifiesImage.class);

                     binp = bitmaps.get(position);
                     bmp = binp.toString();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("picture", bmp.toString());
                    i.putExtra("b", bundle);
                    //  EnterParse();
                    startActivity(i);
                    // passing array index

                    // passing array index
                }
```

second activity:

```
     im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    massage2 = intent.getStringExtra("mas");
    TextView texti = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    texti.setText(massage2);

    Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("bi");

    if (b == null){

    }
    else{
        try {
            String m = b.getString("image");
            myUri = Uri.parse(m);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        String n = currentUser.getUsername();
        name.setText(n);
```

LogCat:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.tepper.myapplication.GridViewActivity$1$1.onAnimationEnd
```

Comment: Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("bi"); change this line as like i mentioned     Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("b"); ,  You have used b to put an bitmap so obviously you need to use same b to retrieve the value

Comment: oh, my mistake, but it crash yet.. in this line :                                      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

Comment: i am really dont know what the problem is

Comment: what error you are getting?? i think there also you did mistake instead of image use picture to get values,

Comment: You should think about caching images instead of sending them througgh activities

Comment: so what i need to do now?